# Is it possible to use QUERY on certain columns from another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, transpose, google-forms, google-query-language

Apologies if this question has been asked, but I’ve searched for it and cannot find the words to explain what I’m trying to do.

I am designing a Google Form that teachers will use to document the accommodations they give their students. How I’ve got it structured is they open the form, select their name, and it takes them to the section of the form for them. Then it submits. Each student is a “question,” and thus a column heading on the Form Responses 1 tab in the linked Sheet. What I’m doing on a previous iteration of this is creating a Form for each teacher, instead of one for all of them. Then I use a Query function on a specific tab for each student, along with some other stuff to get averages. What I need help with is creating these tabs with this version.

Basically, I don’t know if I can write a function that will: Look at ‘Form Responses 1’!1:1, find a specific name, and *then* query all the columns with that name.

My example sheet below has four teachers and each of them have the same four students, but obviously, in real life, they won’t all have the same students, so I can’t make a reference to a specific column range because it won’t always be the same.

Thank you in advance, and let me know if the link or my explanation is broken!

[Sheet:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wP-LJQFDQ--ZbnKZ7r_z_jA4CH7rq9PWTBb8M2p2Cag/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use filter like:

```
={A1:A5, FILTER(B1:H5, B1:H1="aa")}
```

[image]

or query like this:

```
={A1:A6, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B1:H6), "where Col1='bb'"))}
```

[image]

---

the filter is more recommended, tho

Comment: I think that’s going to do what I need! Thank you so much!